# Read-Only program on CD. no installation permitted. Firebird database

Tags: firebird, cd

I have to develop a software for CD. So, the project must run only in CD, without installing to computer. Installing and copying must be impossible from disc. The program is something like Language Learning program. Can I use .NET (c#) environment for such a program? And which databases can I use? (I heard about Firebird).

Comment: Yes, you can use Firebird as [embedded server](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/ufb-cs-embedded.html). Also you can use [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/). And may be something else.

Comment: The question is off-topic here, but forget this approach. No matter how strong your "protection" is, it's just a matter of time before a user smarter than you learns how to scrape the entire content. It's 2016, my recommendation is to use a cloud/service based approach instead, with user authentication. Unless someone emulates your entire service for themselves, you're good.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, can you explain please, what does 'off-topic question' mean? Why my question is off-topic?

Comment: You are asking for recommendations of software to use, which is off topic, and otherwise your question is too broad

Comment: @SaraMurtuzayeva https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @EMBarbosa , thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could use firebird. However, you would need a connection to an external firebird server to be able to do physical operations on the data. Another solution would be to save the data on the client computer. For instance you could restore the database in a profile folder. It is unclear to me whether changes and learn progress should be saved.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.